# “ImportError: No module named” error after "writefile"

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to collect some of the cells in my iPython Notebook into a python script. However, I cannot import a function that's been added to a script with "writefile -a" magic. Here's a 4 cell notebook to replicate the problem:

cell 1: save a function into foo.py

```
%%writefile foo.py

def some_func():
    print 42
```

cell 2: use the function from foo.py

```
from foo import some_func

some_func()
```

This prints 42 succesfully.

cell 3: append another function to foo.py

```
%%writefile foo.py -a

def other_func():
    print 43
```

cell 4: try to import other_func

```
from foo import other_func

other_func()
```

---

> ImportError: cannot import name other_func

Answer (score 3):

You need to [reload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) the module after modifying it:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(foo)
```

In general, this works better with the `import foo` form of the import statement, rather than `from foo import some_func`.  If you have a long module name, you can rename it with `import some_long_module as slm`

Answer (score 1):

IPython has a specific extension "[autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html)" that reloads modules automatically before entering the execution of code typed at the IPython prompt.

It is already included in the standard IPython installation, so in your example, you only need to write:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import foo
```

And then each time you call a specific function of foo, it will be dynamically reloaded before actually executing the cell code, which solves your problem.